# Cannot find JDOM node through xpath after clone

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jdom

I have a xml document, and I use JDOM to parse it and use XPATH API provided by JDOM to find some element, it works well.

Example:

    `<person>
        <info name="gg" age="0" hobby="hi" />
    </person>`

Through API:

```
XPath.selectSingleNode(baseElement,"//*[local-name()='info");
```

I can get the correct info.

Then I try to clone a new baseElement with baseElement.clone().

After that, if I try:

```
XPath.selectSingleNode(baseElementClone,"//*[local-name()='info");
```

I got nothing.

The only diff I can image is that after clone, it will lose the parent info. But I dont why it will affect the search result.

Pls let me know if you think the question is unclear.

BTW, my JDOM version is 1.0

Br,
Tim

Comment: Really, you should be using JDOM 2.0.5, or at least JDOM 1.1.3, JDOM 1.0 is from ... 2004... 11 years ago. Then, you need to add a `']` to your expression.

Comment: You're using XPath 1.0, and XPath 1.0 wasn't very well defined when applied to trees with no document node at the root. In XPath 2.0 it's well-defined that any expression starting with "/" starts by navigating to the document node at the root of the tree, and if there isn't one, it gives you a dynamic error.

Comment: Finally, I find the answer after reading source code of JDOM 2.0, cannot read 1.0 because of something wrong with my nexus.    When you clone a element, it dont have document, during the XPATH evaluate time, it will check if we have document firstly, if not, then directly return a empty result. After I find this, I just create a empty document, and add the cloned element into this document, this solves my problem.

Comment: If you are using JDOM 2.0 then you should use the new XPath API and it will allow you to do XPath expressions on disconnected content. Please read up here: https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-Feature-XPath-Upgrade